# How to customize the size of Featured Images or Post Thumbnails in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, css, post-thumbnails

I have added custom image as featured image but I have add a bigger size image but when I see the post I got the small image in the post.

My question is how to set or customize the figure size of that image?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
the_post_thumbnail(); // Without parameter ->; Thumbnail
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' ); // Medium-large resolution (default 768px x no height limit max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); // Large resolution (default 1024px x 1024px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); // Original image resolution (unmodified)
the_post_thumbnail( array( 100, 100 ) ); // Other resolutions (height, width)
```

Comment: You can also refer [https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/)